# Android Firebase how to save and retrieve data under specific user

Tags: android, firebase, save, cloud, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to integrate my app with firebase to save simple data on cloud.

**Example:**

user open the app and login.

user write some stuff,the data saved on cloud.

when the user will use the app again he will see his data.

i have read the docs but  i coud not find any example how the
structure works between the user and the data.
user logged in , now how to save strings/object for that user?

**what i tried:**

user login or authenticate the user

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.addAuthStateListener(new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
        if (authData != null) {
            // user is logged in
        } else {
            // user is not logged in
        }
    }
});
```

**now how to save under that user objects/strings?**

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using and old Android API for Firebase.
With the latest Android API there is no more need for `"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com"` in your code.
I would suggest to migrate, using [that migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android).

Once you have logged your user following that [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/)

Then you can store user information like in that [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#basic_write) :

```
String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("name").setValue("John");
```

Don't forget to change your security rule in Firebase to make sure only this user can access his own data: [guide here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security). It's very easy and quick to do and very important for keeping your user's data private.