# Username and password wont save in Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Below is my code for both my registration page and sign in page in android studio. The code runs however when registering the user's details does not seem to upload onto my firebase database. Therefore unable to use this data when on my sign in page. Unsure on how to rectify this within my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package com.example.spaceattack;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText emailId, password;
    Button btnSignUp;
    TextView tvSignIn;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        emailId = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        password = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        tvSignIn = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = emailId.getText().toString();
                String pwd = password.getText().toString();
                if(email.isEmpty()) {
                    emailId.setError("Please enter email id");
                    emailId.requestFocus();
                }
                else if(pwd.isEmpty()) {
                    password.setError("Enter your password");
                    password.requestFocus();
                }
                else if(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Fields are Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(! (email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())) {

                    mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd) .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"SignUp Unsuccessful, Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                            else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, WaterActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
                else {

                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });

        tvSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent (RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}







package com.example.spaceattack;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText emailId, password;
    Button btnSignUp;
    TextView tvSignUp;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        emailId = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        password = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        tvSignUp = findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {


            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (mFirebaseUser != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        };

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = emailId.getText().toString();
                String pwd = password.getText().toString();
                if (email.isEmpty()) {
                    emailId.setError("Please enter email id");
                    emailId.requestFocus();
                } else if (pwd.isEmpty()) {
                    password.setError("Enter your password");
                    password.requestFocus();
                } else if (email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Fields are Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())) {

                    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Error, Please Login Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Intent intToHome = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WaterActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intToHome);
                            }

                        }

                    });
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });

        tvSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intSignUp = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WaterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intSignUp);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the code in your question writes to the Firebase Realtime Database as far as I can see. Keep in mind that Firebase Authentication only writes user profiles to its own internal storage. If you *also* want that information to be stored in the database, you'll have to do that from your application code yourself.

Comment: Would you be able to show how the code could be changed using Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: That's a new question, but luckily one that has been asked before. Have a look at some of these results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+write+user+data, specifically https://stackoverflow.com/q/43291815, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38812626, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46442550, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682667